# How can I concatenate strings and use them as a list name?

Tags: r

I have these lists: `models_results_ZL`, `models_results_B2` and `models_results_B4` that contain numbers.

For example:

```
> models_results_ZL
[1] 245.1907896  29.9200000   0.9000181  34.0000000
> models_results_B2
[1] 264.9851283  53.7100000   0.9163977  32.0000000
> models_results_B4
[1] 289.7529856  52.5600000   0.9229745  31.0000000
```

I have the list `both_constr_satisfied` that contains "B2","B4". This list is not static. It may contains different combinations of "ZL", "B2" and "B4".
For example:

```
> both_constr_satisfied
[1] "B2" "B4"
```

Regarding the values of `both_constr_satisfied` I want to get the first value of the corresponding `models_results` lists. e.g. For this example I want to get `models_results_B2[1]` and `models_results_B4[1]` and store them to a new list. e.g. `new_list = [264.9851283, 289.7529856]`

How can I concatenate strings and use them as a list name?

I'm trying the following code, but `var_name` is just a string not a list.

```
VQ_options=c()
for (option in length(both_constr_satisfied)){
    assign(var_name, paste0("models_results_",both_constr_satisfied[option+1]))
    VQ_options = var_name[1]
  }
```

Comment: Can you please add reproducible example of both `model_results` and `both_constr_satisfied` lists

Comment: @Sotos There is no list named `model_results`. There are 3 different lists that have the same initial name.  `model_results_ZL`,  `model_results_B2` and  `model_results_B4`. I want to concatenate `model_results` with the values of  `both_constr_satisfied` and use these as lists. I added examples of these. I will add also for `both_constr_satisfied`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
# Some data 
a <- list(models_results_ZL=1:10, models_results_B2=10:1, models_results_B4=11:20)
a
$models_results_ZL
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$models_results_B2
[1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1

$models_results_B4
[1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

both_constr_satisfied <- list(c("B2", "B4"))

# change names according the both_constr_satisfied list
a <- setNames(a, unlist(lapply(strsplit(names(a), "_"), "[", 3)))
names(a)
[1] "ZL" "B2" "B4"

# extract the first value, respectively
lapply(a[unlist(both_constr_satisfied)], "[", 1)
$B2
[1] 10

$B4
[1] 11
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!!